# curl_exec() automatically runs var_dump()

Tags: php, curl, var-dump

I've been working on a PHP project using cURL to access external API.
Even though connecting via API is successfully done, one subtle thing bothers me...
That is, "return values of curl_exec($curl) are dumped out automatically".

Here's my codes.

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ["Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"]);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://...');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($some_post_data));

$result = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
```

That's all.

I didn't write "var_dump" or "print_r" or anything to output the result.
Nevertheless, there's always dumped result values on the display... more precisely, the dumping occurs at the line

```
$result = curl_exec($curl);
```

Does anyone know what's happening?

Comment: Can you add the output you are seeing to the question? Also, perhaps the response *looks* like a var_dump? You could try the same in postman and see if response is the same.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I forgot to set 
 CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER true, and simply adding that option solved my problem... thanks anyway!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER to TRUE to return the transfer as a string of the return value of curl_exec() instead of outputting it out directly.

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

Comment: Wow... really a rudimental mistake... Thank you so much! Solved completely.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: I appreciate for a guidance. Is 'mark as accepted' correctly done..? Anyway, it helped me so much and thank you again!